# Is it possible that the first parameter is optional and second parameter is compulsory in function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is fuction:

```
let Func = (a=10, b) => {
  return a + b; 
 }
```

Function Calling:

```
Func(null,20);
```

or

```
Func(20);
```

I want to get output : **30**

*Is there other way of calling function and get output 30?*

Comment: no optional parameters with defaut values must be the last argument

Comment: What‘s your point? What do you expect? To save characters?

Answer (score 3):

There is no function overloading in JavaScript. The most you can get is that you can use named parameters in functions:

```js
let Func = ({a=10, b}) => {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(Func({b: 20}));
```

This obviously, changes the way you call the function, but it supports omitting the optional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

> Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed.

You can pass `undefined` as the first parameter. As said above, note that passing `null` won't work:

```js
const Func = (a = 10, b) => {
  return a + b; 
}

console.log(Func(undefined,20));
```

If you *can't* pass `undefined` for whatever reason, then the best you'll be able to do is to explicitly test `a` inside the function, and reassign if needed. For example:

```js
const Func = (a = 10, b) => {
  if (a === null) a = 10;
  return a + b; 
}

console.log(Func(null,20));
```

Comment: If you could also add why undefined works but not null, that would help OP

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use a [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Idea is to create an array of values and set it to necessary argument. You can add default values based on the priority as well. This way, you do not need to construct your inputs or pass undefined.

```js
const Func = (...rest) => {
  const [ b, a ] = [ ...rest, 10 ]
  return a + b; 
}

console.log(Func(20));
console.log(Func(5, 20));
```

You can even extend it to work like this, but say you only want to pass values for `b` and `d`. This will create problems and you will have to rely on one of the approaches discussed in other answers(*[preferred answer in my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51297940/3783478)*). But, if problem statement is straight forward, you can give this a try.

```js
const Func = (...rest) => {
  const defaultValues = [ 10, 5, 20 ];
  const [ b, a, c, d ] = [ ...rest, ...defaultValues ]
  return a + b + c + d; 
}

console.log(Func(20));
console.log(Func(5, 20));
console.log(Func(5, 20, 25));
console.log(Func(5, 20, 25, 35));
```

Comment: **Note:** This is not a very extensible approach and can get confusing. But this will suffice for given problem. If you think, there is anything wrong/incorrect/problematic, please do comment with your vote.